# Can't understand why UISegmentedControl is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift

Just messing around with a simple iOS app in Swift that displays an image view and segmented control underneath with 3 options. I'm just trying to get the image to swap out based on which option is chosen from the segmented control. I have this simple code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var gallery = ["apple", "banana", "coconut"]
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

  @IBAction func changeSegment(sender: AnyObject) {
    let segmentedControl = sender as? UISegmentedControl
    if let index = segmentedControl?.selectedSegmentIndex {
      imageView.image = UIImage(named: gallery[index])
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


}
```

I keep running into an error that prints out "(lldb)". It looks like it hits a breakpoint at:

```
let segmentedControl = sender as? UISegmentedControl
```

not sure why. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If all it says is `(lldb)`, that does sound like it's pausing at a breakpoint. Maybe there's a breakpoint there. What does the Breakpoint inspector tell you? Does it help if you quit and clean out the DerivedData folder?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Must have set it accidentally and not realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a breakpoint on the side of your code. I would clean your file and run.